Is there another way to reduce the many dimensions of string theory to the observed 4 dimensions?
I understand that string theory works best with many more dimensions than the 4 observed dimensions (1 time, 3 space). To reduce the visible dimensions, I always read that it could be that most of the dimensions are curved to a microscopic scale, which makes them invisible for us, whereas only 4 dimensions are almost flat at a macroscopic scale.
I realise that there is another way to reduce the number of visible dimensions. E.g., assume a three dimensional space with two phases, e.g. steam and water. Then the border surface is two dimensional. Adding a third phase, e.g. ice, then the border line between the three phases is one dimensional.
Could it be that our universe is a border surface where many phases come together? I never saw this idea when I read about string theory. Is it possible to reduce 11 dimensions to 4 dimensions by assuming the existence of 8 phases in the 11 dimensional space? Did I miss something? I can hardly believe that I am the first one to think of it.
If possible, the creation of the universe could be a limited region with the eighth phase entering the border surface of the 7 other phases, just like a piece of ice that drops down and starts to float on the water, creating the one dimensional border line. 
Or it could be a phase transition, just like a small part of the water that is converted into ice.

Yes such models exist in string theory. They are called intersecting brane-world models.

Thanks. Now I have a name and I can search for it.
